# Anova and mixed effect models (lm4 / nlme) return complete different effects

Tags: r, anova, variance, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

As a continuation of a previous [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959054/why-is-there-a-dramatic-difference-between-aov-and-lmer), I would like to address a similar experience.

Subjects completed an experiment in which their electrodermal activity was recorded. For each subject there are 72 observations, making the dataset  ~40000 obs. long.

- As a depended variable is the electrodermal response amplitude of a
  subject for each observation.
- As fixed effects are binary variables (and their interaction), such
  as whether a subject had faced childhood maltreatment during the
  early year and whether they have experienced recent adversities.
- The variable "Subject" gets to be my random effect within the lmer
  function.

In R that would be translated into:

```
lmer(formula = response.Amplitudes ~ childhood.Adversity * 
               recent.Adversity + (1|Subject), data = data)
```

Using anova and not the mixed a effected models, that would be:

```
aov(lm(response.Amplitudes ~ childhood.Adversity * 
          recent.Adversity, data = data)
```

The outcome of the first (mixed effects) formula gives a significant main effect of one of the fixed effects while an anova gives a high significance of both main effects and the interaction. Which is a huge difference

Obviously, the most logical explanation is that in my random effect, that of Subject, there is a huge variance.

Now, my question is: If this is the case, how can I prove that the huge difference between the models lies on the variance in the random effect? Is there a way to prove this, other than just looking at the outcome?

** Since I am new to the mixed models and that statistical approach, I recognize that the way of describing the problem lacks information or may be misleading. Please, let me know if I can provide any further information to make it more accurate.

Comment: If you have a repeated measures design, your ANOVA is clearly not appropriate (because the independence assumption is violated) and you shouldn't even look at its result. You can compare an `lmer` fit with a corresponding `lm` fit with the `anova.merMod` method, i.e., `anova(lmer(y ~ x + (1 | g)), lm(y ~ x))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any ANOVA or Kruskal Wallis test to see if the subject affects the outcome using formula `response.Amplitudes ~ Subject`. Just test if `Subject` is significant here. If yes, you might have a [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox) here. You can test how big this influence is by calculating the `R2` of the `response.Amplitudes ~ childhood.Adversity * recent.Adversity + (1|Subject)` model e.g. using [Nakagawa's R2](https://easystats.github.io/performance/reference/r2_nakagawa.html).

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your fast responses.
It turns out, as @Roland suggested, that the independency is violated with the repeated measures. That is the reason for the odd result of the anova.

Creating a new data frame with a single mean for each subject and then running an anova, returns the same result as the mixed models.

@danloo thanks for the [Nakagawa](https://easystats.github.io/performance/reference/r2_nakagawa.html) package, I did not know about it.